# Mails error : Sending from website ASP.net (Works locally : 1and1 hosting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, email, web

Here my code to send an email on my website (using 1and1 host).
This code work in local but return false when it's online :

```
    [WebMethod()]
   public static bool Send_requete(string nom, string mail, string sujet, string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
            Msg.From = new MailAddress("admin@mywebsite.fr");
            Msg.To.Add("someone@example.com");
            Msg.Subject = "CONTACT : De " + nom + " " + sujet;
            Msg.Body = "De : " + mail + Environment.NewLine + " Message : " + msg;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("auth.smtp.1and1.fr", 587);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@mywebsite.fr", "mypass");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(Msg);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Someone have an idea considering that i cant really know where it crash from the server side,
Regards.

Comment: Perhaps you should actually catch the exception and see what is, rather than just returning false? Something like `catch(Exception ex) { Log(ex); }`...

Comment: I'll try to return the string of the exception yes, but seems like it dont even go in the method.

Comment: Well the way you would find out what it's doing would be to add logging.

Comment: "The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer"". Seems like it is a security problem linked to the host.

Comment: http://hpics.li/4d9ff6f : My Error